# Why does this clustered index has more cost than the same non-clustered in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am somewhat new to execution plans. I have always understood clustered indexes to be significantly faster because the actual data row is included in the leaf level of the index tree, whereas non-clustered contains only the indexed column value plus pointers to the location of the remaining row data. therefore, non-clustered has more IO than clustered.

To test this, I used a 1,000,000 record table with `EmployeeID` (the first column) as the primary key, and then also added a non-clustered index on the same field. I then used query hints to compare the results of each index being used.

```
Select EmployeeID from Employees with(index(PK_EmployeeID))
go

select EmloyeeID from Employees with(index(IX_EmployeeID))
go
```

The results show that there is more IO and query cost (relative to batch) for clustered than the non-clustered. Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 4):

For your test query, the index is a "covering" index, because it already contains all columns required for the result set. Therefore, no additional reads for the actual table are required. And because the index is smaller (less pages), the access is faster.
The clustered index is actually the table itself, ordered by the index. Because it contains more columns, more page reads are required.